# How to filter HTTP logs in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, .net-6.0

I am using HTTP Logging in my ASP.NET 6.0 application.
How can I filter out (not log) specific HTTP requests and responses based on their contents/address? In my case it's the built-in success health check I do not want logged.

My logging implementation follows this instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(options =>
    {
        options.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
    });
    builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();
    /.../
    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseHttpLogging();
    app.MapHealthChecks("/hc");
    /.../
```

P.S. The application is very frequently probed by Kubernetes (out of my control) and the health check success logs are just flooding the logging system.

Comment: Do you want to achieve a scenario like when user access a specified controller/action, if this action return 200, It will not log anything but if action return 400, it will log this request?

Comment: @XinranShen Yes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `app.UseHttpLogging();` I used:

```
    app.UseWhen(
        context => !(context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/hc")
                             && context.Response.StatusCode == 200),
        builder => builder.UseHttpLogging()
    );
```

Comment: Hi @user1713059, I try this code, But when the endpoint return 400, It also will not be logged. Then I debug about this, I find that before request access into endpoint, the response will default be 200, So it will not log about it. But after the reuqest return from endpoint with 400 statecode, It will also not log anthing, Do you find the same issue?